# Swagger with OpenApi

Tags: swagger, jax-rs, openapi

I have a project with 2 parts of request / WS, part1 and part2
I wrote 2 yamel part1 and part2 with Swagger Editor, and now I would like to host my Swagger on the tomcat on local until production, using the 2 yaml files (so user will be able to choose part1 or part2)
How can I do that please ?
I don't use Spring Boot, but I use spring-core, beans, context and so on ...

I tried to add the dependance springdoc-openapi-ui
I put part1.yaml and part2.yaml on src/main/resources/api
And I put a file "swagger-config.yaml" on the root (src/main/resources/)

springdoc:
swagger-ui:
urls:

- url: "/api/part1.yaml"
  name: "part1"
- url: "/api/part2.yaml"
  name: "part2"

Should I add spring-boot ?
What is the link between OpenAPI and swagger-ui ?

I added 2 generates on pom.xml, one for part1, and one for part2, with generator jaxrs-spec.
Can I remove swagger annotations ?

Thank you very much for your help, I am lost...